# Character build- Baron Harkonnen

Tags: pathfinder-1e, npc

I want to build an NPC villain inspired from the Dune character, Baron Vladimir Harkonen. Said character is an extremely sadistic, cruel, corrupt noble who is ugly and so fat he uses a flying chair to move.

Note that while Dune is a Sci-Fi setting, we're are in an classical fantasy adventure, so he use magic instead of technology. For keeping him as a threat I'd like to make him a spellcaster of some kind; his physical abilites are limited by his obesity. Alternately, I could see making him a threat with just magical items and an UMD score, since he is super-rich he can afford them; my concern with that route is I don't want to give him too much equipment because the players could manage to loot it.

Social skills are not required, but bluff and intimidate are in character so I'd like some.

Ideally, he would use some form of magical flying 'chair' and have inhibited movement.

It would be an cr 12 encounter, knowing he have a few guards (at least 2 fighters lvl 10). The baron himself would be lvl 9-10 with pc wealth. Maybe a little more than PC wealth but i can't find rules for calculate the cr of that.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] for a quick site introduction (and a badge!). Keep in mind our format is quite different from a forum. As it stands this question appears to be actually asking several different questions. You can get a better response by focusing on one thing at a time and asking separate questions, such as "Is there anything in the game like an mobile chair" and "are there rules for immobility in pathfinder?". Thank you for participating!

Comment: @sdjz I feel like you're looking at it wrong; this is a character build question and those are restrictions. The question *does* need more information (specifically ability score spread, class levels, and if its ok to have them be not-human come to mind). The restriction of a floating chair is part of the character build; they need to have a (probably magic) item that does *x*. Is a valid restraint.

Comment: I went through and cleaned up grammar and a couple sentences. Please check that I didn't change what you're asking at all and try to add some details (restrictions) to make sure that we can actually help with this; you should make it as specific as possible so there is a correct answer, not a bunch of equally good ones. You really should review [the Meta post about character questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-build-or-optimization-questions-on-topic) to find more information as well.

Comment: you worded the question nearly perfectly. The only thing is while i want him to use his chair to move around most of the time, it don't need to be flying if there is no such thing : as a spellcaster he can cas fly. In other words, would prefer if it is flying, it must be mobile, but the character can cast it's own flying

Comment: i am looking for magic items and a class that allows spellcasting or enough synergy with magic items that the baron is a threat in combat despite his disability. Anctuals mechanics for his disability would be nice, as well for his magical chair.

Comment: Good social skills, especially in bluff and intimidate are not required would be cool too, but not required. He could be carrying a lot of magical items (he is wealthy) but if it goes beyond the wealth of a pc of his level, actual mecanics for cr change caused by it would be nice, but keep in mind problem from the fact that magical items can be looted.

Comment: It looks like you’ve created multiple accounts (4 so far). If you plan to use the site that much, consider [**registering**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) this account, and then having your other accounts [**merged together**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: You should be editing your question, not posting comments to yourself. Comments are actually eventually removed to save space, but your question is permanent (and what will determine if/when it's actually reopened). We still need to know build *restraints* such as level, ability scores, and spending limit.

Comment: I've nominated this question for reopening (I've basically known the direction of an appropriate answer.) Hopefully the community agrees with me that you've made it specific enough... or comes in with more criteria to make it specific.

Comment: It still sounds *very* broad, there are many class combinations possible here.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:gm-techniques] tag since it is intended for "arts and methods applied to gamemastering", not for character generation questions.

Comment: @ShadowKras If it needs to be more specific, OP needs specific things to address

Comment: @Ifusaso the problem isn't that he should to be more specific, but that we could easily get 10 answers that are all *valid* and still of different classes, with different feats, magic items, etc.